# Run powershell script with additional command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I'd want to execute a powershell script and add Send-mailMessage from the commandline interface. My example command is shown below.

The credentials are stored and converted via ConvertTo-SecureString in the autoemail.ps1 script.

.\autoemail.ps1  Send-MailMessage -From 'sample@email.com' -To 'sample@email.com' -Subject 'The email subject!' -Body "This is the body" -SmtpServer 'smtpserver.com' -Credential $creds

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: The script is working fine if I put the "send-MailMessage*****" into the script. But I need to run the following command into powershell command line 

.\autoemail.ps1 Send-MailMessage -From 'sample@email.com' -To 'sample@email.com' -Subject 'The email subject!' -Body "This is the body" -SmtpServer 'smtpserver.com' -Credential $creds

Answer (score 0):

> The credentials are stored and converted via ConvertTo-SecureString in the autoemail.ps1 script.

In order for the variables in `autoemail.ps1` to persist in the calling scope, use [the `.` dot-source operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#dot-sourcing-operator-):

```
. .\autoemail.ps1 
Send-MailMessage -From 'sample@email.com' -To 'sample@email.com' -Subject 'The email subject!' -Body "This is the body" -SmtpServer 'smtpserver.com' -Credential $creds
```

Comment: It appears to be working now, but I need to add the ..\autoemail.ps1 and -To 'email.com' -Subject 'The email subject!' -Body 'Test 06222023'. please see the below command

..\autoemail.ps1 -To 'email.com' -Subject 'The email subject!' -Body 'Test 06222023'

The *-To 'email.com' -Subject 'The email subject!' -Body 'Test 06222023'*  is not working

Comment: basically I just want to add value when running autoemail.ps1

Answer (score 0):

This question touches quiet some security risks...

First of all, (CMD) "*The commandline*" doesn't support .Net classes as [PSCredential](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.pscredential) or [SecureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring), see also: [Send a SecureString Password from CMD file to Powershell](https://serverfault.com/a/877117/857796). The correct way to implement this is to make this password-less by allowing the user account that runs the command to sent messages.

Knowing the the `PSCredential` class uses the `SecuredString` class:

> ⚠️ [**Important**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.security.securestring#remarks)
>
> We recommend that you don't use the SecureString class for new development on .NET (Core) or when you migrate existing code to .NET (Core). For more information, see [SecureString shouldn't be used](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md).

Besides:

> ⚠️ [**Warning**](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage#description)
>
> The Send-MailMessage cmdlet is obsolete. This cmdlet does not guarantee secure connections to SMTP servers. While there is no immediate replacement available in PowerShell, we recommend you do not use Send-MailMessage. For more information, see [Platform Compatibility note DE0005](https://aka.ms/SendMailMessage).

Anyways, PowerShell variables like `$creds` will not survive the CMD commandline, therefore the `.\automail.ps1` scripts will need to store the credentials in e.g. a file:

```
Get-Credential | Export-Clixml .\creds.xml
```

and reload that in the other command:

```
PowerShell.exe -C "$creds = Import-Clixml .\creds.xml; Send-MailMessage -From 'sample@email.com' -To 'sample@email.com' -Subject 'The email subject!' -Body "This is the body" -SmtpServer 'smtpserver.com' -Credential $creds"
```

The safety (and the limitation) lays in the fact that the stored credential will only work under the user and computer that created it.